# Assign array value to typedef struct array variable in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm using a library that has a typedef struct that contains a few variables and an array.  I'm trying to pass a pointer to a variable of this type to another function and assign values into the array.

```
//typedef in library file
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int arr[5];
} MyType;
```

...
This is in another file

```
void foo()
{
    MyType newtype;
    //...lots of code

    setArray( &newtype );

return;
}

void setArray ( MyType* mytype )
{
    mytype->arr = {
        1,2,3,4,5,
    };

return;
}
```

When I try to compile this code I get the following error on the line with

```
mytpe->arr = {
```

*Expected expression before '{' token*

I've tried it a few different ways such as `mytype->arr[5] = {` but I get various syntax errors.

I'm new to C but I understand that an array really acts as a pointer to the first element in the array.  Is what I'm trying to do not possible and I need to loop through the indices of each array and assign them one at a time?

Comment: `mytype->arr[0] = 1; mytype->arr[1] = 2; ...`

Comment: So `arr` has no type? Looks weird.

Comment: "an array really acts as a pointer" **NO!** An array is **not** a pointer! The name of the array is just converted to a pointer to the first element for **most** (i.e. **not** all!) uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign to arrays like that. You have to do it element-wise, like:

```
mytype->arr[0] = 1;
mytype->arr[1] = 2;
...
```

or using a function like [memcpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

```
const int values[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
memcpy(mytype->arr, values, sizeof values);
```

Better make sure the sizes and types fit.

Note that in an initialization (part of an array declaration and definition), you can set the array in one "step". But this is a different thing.